# Read windows truststore certificates using python

Tags: python, windows, docker, truststore

Please i need to read certificates from the truststore in a windows system .. i am using for that python and i am executing the code in a docker container ... i tried the " wincertstore " python lib but i got this error and i didn't understood what i did wrong to get that

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "agents/common/truststorescanner/agent.py", line 3, in <module>
    import wincertstore 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wincertstore.py", line 23, in <module>
    from ctypes import WinDLL, FormatError, string_at, pointer
ImportError: cannot import name 'WinDLL'
```

And is there other alternatives to read certs in windows truststore ?
and thank you ..

Comment: Why do you expect to import a Windows specific module inside a Linux based Container (at least guessing from the / marked path it is not a Windows based Python)?

Comment: The point is that he's trying to get a certificate, presumably to access a url.  On windows there's an easy way to do it, how should he do it on Linux?